# Shorthand for defining function in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

Accidentally I written a code like below,

```
var x = {hai:10,test(){ alert("I am alive")}};
x.test(); //alerting the value
```

It is working fine and I wonder how this code is working? since it was considered previously as an invalid grammar. And I know, In `ECMAscript 6`, there is a shorthand for assigning properties has been introduced.

***Example:***

```
var x = 5, y = {x};  // is as same as var x=5,y={x:x};
```

But I am not sure about the function definition. Can anyone explain about it with proof from documentation?

Comment: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) - there's proof and explanation in one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a Feature coming with ES2015. You can skip the function-keyword for **method**-definitions (not for plain functions).
So `{ doSth(){/*...*/ } }` is simply a shorthand for `{ doSth: function(){/*...*/ } }`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions

Answer (score 2):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), a shorter syntax for method
>   definitions on objects initializers is introduced. It is a shorthand
>   for a function assigned to the method's name.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>   property( parameters… ) {},
>   *generator( parameters… ) {},
> // also with computed keys:
>   [property]( parameters… ) {},
>   *[generator]( parameters… ) {},
> // compare ES5 getter/setter syntax:
>   get property() {},
>   set property(value) {}
> };
> ```
>
> You are now able to shorten this to:
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>   foo() {},
>   bar() {}
> };
> ```

MDN Links to [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Enhanced Object Literals
> ```
>
> Object literals are extended to support setting the prototype at
>   construction, shorthand for foo: foo assignments, defining methods,
>   making super calls, and computing property names with expressions.
>   Together, these also bring object literals and class declarations
>   closer together, and let object-based design benefit from some of the
>   same conveniences.
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>     // __proto__
>     __proto__: theProtoObj,
>     // Shorthand for ‘handler: handler’
>     handler,
>     // Methods
>     toString() {
>      // Super calls
>      return "d " + super.toString();
>     },
>     // Computed (dynamic) property names
>     [ 'prop_' + (() => 42)() ]: 42
> };
> ```

Reference : https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals